# What is the proper way of reading .json data from a RestAPI GET call into either an interface, class,...etc in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, weather-api

Currently learning Angular and API calls by writing a Weather app using WeatherAPI (https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/WeatherAPI.com/WeatherAPI/1.0.2-oas3-oas3.1-oas3.1/#/)

I am writing a `Dashboard` component that displays the location, temperature, and weather conditions (clear, cloudy,...etc.). as well as change the associated div's background between a "night" image and a "day" image. While I managed the former, it seems that the image URL isn't being loaded, so the component's background is in default white.

I wrote a DashboardService that calls the API:

```js
//dashboard.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs';

import { API } from '../const';
import { ApiCurrentReturnModel } from '../schema';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * 
   * @param currLocation the name of the area to be queried for
   * @returns current weather data of location specified
   */
  getCurrent(currLocation : string) {
    const url = API.URL.replace("{ call }", API.CURRENT)
                       .replace("{ q }", currLocation.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                       .replace("{ key }", API.KEY);
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

which returns the following (example) .json from WeatherAPI

```json
{
  "location": {
    "name": "New York",
    "region": "New York",
    "country": "United States of America",
    "lat": 40.71,
    "lon": -74.01,
    "tz_id": "America/New_York",
    "localtime_epoch": 1658522976,
    "localtime": "2022-07-22 16:49"
  },
  "current": {
    "last_updated_epoch": 1658522700,
    "last_updated": "2022-07-22 16:45",
    "temp_c": 34.4,
    "temp_f": 93.9,
    "is_day": 1,
    "condition": {
      "text": "Partly cloudy",
      "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
      "code": 1003
    },
    "wind_mph": 16.1,
    "wind_kph": 25.9,
    "wind_degree": 180,
    "wind_dir": "S",
    "pressure_mb": 1011,
    "pressure_in": 29.85,
    "precip_mm": 0,
    "precip_in": 0,
    "humidity": 31,
    "cloud": 75,
    "feelslike_c": 37,
    "feelslike_f": 98.6,
    "vis_km": 16,
    "vis_miles": 9,
    "uv": 8,
    "gust_mph": 11.6,
    "gust_kph": 18.7,
    "air_quality": {
      "co": 293.70001220703125,
      "no2": 18.5,
      "o3": 234.60000610351562,
      "so2": 12,
      "pm2_5": 13.600000381469727,
      "pm10": 15,
      "us-epa-index": 1,
      "gb-defra-index": 2
    }
  }
}
```

My current plan is to utilze the `is_day` value in the .json to change the link to the background image. Said link is stored in a variable called `currWeatherBackgroundUrl`. This is done in the `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` function in `dashboard.component.ts`

```js
//dashboard.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardService } from '../service/dashboard.service';
import { ApiCurrent, ApiCurrentReturnModel, ApiLocation } from '../schema';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css', '../app.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
  private currentLocation: string = 'Hanoi';

  private apiResult!: ApiCurrentReturnModel; //interface for reading .json data
  private apiCurrent!: ApiCurrent; //child of ApiCurrentReturnModel
  private apiLocation!: ApiLocation; //child of ApiCurrentReturnModel

  // AN ATTEMPT AT USING A TERNARY OPERATION TO DETERMINE WHICH IMAGE TO USE AS THE DIV'S BACKGROUND
  //private currWeatherBackgroundUrl: string = this.currentData.current.is_day == 1 ? '../assets/bg/daytime-image.jpg' : '../assets/bg/night-image.jpg';

  private currWeatherBackgroundUrl = ''; //link init as empty

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {
    //Same ternary operation attempt but in constructor instead.
    //this.currWeatherBackgroundUrl = this.currentData.current.is_day == 1 ? '../assets/bg/daytime-image.jpg' : '../assets/bg/night-image.jpg';
  }

  //ngOnInit life cycle hook
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData(); //read data from json
    this.getCurrentWeatherBackground(); //choose background image
    window.alert("ngOnInit"); //debug alert
    
  }

  loadData() {
    this.dashboardService.getCurrent(this.currentLocation).subscribe( rs => {
      let result = rs as ApiCurrentReturnModel;
      this.apiResult = result;
      this.apiLocation = result.location;
      this.apiCurrent = result.current;
    }
    );
  }

  getCurrentWeatherBackground() {
    if (this.currentData.current.is_day != 1) {
      //this.currWeatherBackgroundUrl = '../assets/bg/night-image.jpg';
      this.setCurrWeatherBackgroundUrl('../assets/bg/night-image.jpg');
      window.alert("night");
    }
    else {
      //this.currWeatherBackgroundUrl = '../assets/bg/daytime-image.jpg';
      this.setCurrWeatherBackgroundUrl('../assets/bg/daytime-image.jpg');
      window.alert("day");
    }
    
    window.alert("getCurrWeatherBg");
  }

  get currentData() {
    return this.apiResult;
  }

  getCurrWeatherBackgroundUrl() {
    return this.currWeatherBackgroundUrl;
  }

  setCurrWeatherBackgroundUrl(url: string) {
    this.currWeatherBackgroundUrl = url;
  }
}
```

However, `ngOnInit()` is unable to execute `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` as indicated by the debug alert not being executed. The same can be said of the alerts within `getCurrentWeatherBackgroundUrl()`. As a result, the initialized variable to hold the URL remains empty.

Additionally, `ApiCurrent`, `ApiLocation`, and `ApiCurrentReturnModel` are interfaces that stores the .json data as follows:

```json
export interface ApiLocation {
    name: string
    region: string
    country: string
    lat: number
    lon: number
    tz_id: string 
    localtime_epoch: number
    localtime: string
}

export interface ApiCurrent {
    last_updated_epoch: number
    last_updated: string
    temp_c: number
    temp_f: number
    is_day: number
    condition: {
        text: string
        icon: string
        code: number
    }
    wind_mph: number
    wind_kph: number
    wind_degree: number
    wind_dir: string
    pressure_mb: number
    pressure_in: number
    precip_mm: number
    precip_in: number
    humidity: number
    cloud: number
    feelslike_c: number
    feelslike_f: number
    vis_km: number
    vis_miles: number
    uv: number
    gust_mph: number
    gust_kph: number
    air_quality: {
        co: number
        no2: number
        o3: number
        so2: number
        pm2_5: number
        pm10: number
        us_epa_index: number
        gb_defra_index: number
        
    }    
}

export interface ApiCurrentReturnModel {
    location: any
    current: any
}
```

I have verified that upon manually setting the URL in `currWeatherBackgroundUrl` to either of the links used `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` properly sets the background image of the div.

I've tried to use ternary operations to determine which image to use as indivated by the commented-out expressions in `dashboard.component.ts`.

More notably, upon removal of the `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` function from `ngOnInit()`, both `loadData()` and the alert is executed. Meaning the issue must be within `getCurrentWeatherBackground()`. I suspect it has something to with how I'm reading the .json data, as the `is_day` in said .json is typed as an int32. All I'm really doing in regards of reading the .json data is within `loadData()`.

Why is it that the `currWeatherBackgroundUrl` isn't being changed? Why are the if-statements in `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` not triggering?

Sorry for the long post! I really appreciate any help and you staying with me throughout this process!

Comment: In your `ngOninit()` you are calling `loadData()` and immediately calling `getCurrentWeatherBackground()`, in a syncronous flow. However `loadData()` calls the api asyncronously, and when your `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` is called, the result from `loadData()` will not be available yet.
Move the `getCurrentWeatherBackground()` call to inside the `subscribe(...)` inside `loadData()`. And while you are there, you can access the `res` directly to check the `is_day` property from your json.